# Micro SD card fails to be detected in RHEL 7.2, while Windows 10 asks to format it each time is inserted

Tags: linux, data-recovery, sd-card, memory-card

I have the following MicroSD card which fails to be detected on RHEL 7.2, while Windows 10 asks to format it each time it is inserted.

The card is a MicroSD HC I Class 6 (8GB)

In RHEL 7.2, dmesg log says:

```
[41668.794800] mmc0: card 59b4 removed
[41676.033143] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[41676.132689] mmc0: card lacks mandatory SD Status function
[41676.132714] mmc0: new SD card at address 59b4
[rashah@oc1245342277 ~]$
```

While Windows Disk management shows it as RAW partition.

Looked around on the Internet, but couldn't find any relevant answer.

Is this memory card dead or can be recovered?